# getting svchost path by PID using python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, psutil

i am trying to get svchost.exe path by PID using python. i tried it using psutil but i got access denied error.

here is my code-

```
  import psutil
  p = psutil.Process(1832)
  print p.exe()
```

Comment: The *Access denied* message is nothing to do with Python. That is Windows telling you you can't have what you want.

Comment: yes, but can i do it with cmd? i didnt catch the svchost path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get process path using `wmi` module.

Here is a sample code for you. This code fids all process named svchost and return path to the process. This returns full information on process.

```
import wmi
import psutil

c = wmi.WMI ()
process = psutil.Process(2276)

process_name = process.name()

for process in c.Win32_Process(name=process_name):
  if process.ExecutablePath:
            print (process.ExecutablePath)
```

**Output**

```
 c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe
c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe
c:\windows\system32\svchost.exe
```

Comment: thank you. i need it for a specific process. there is a way to get it with PID or by PID instead name?

Comment: use psutils to get name from pid and then just use that name to find path.

Comment: thank you. but i prefer use the PID only because i want to check if svchost is a real svchost or its a malware named svchost

Comment: `for process in c.Win32_Process(ProcessId=10084):
           if process.ExecutablePath:
                    print (process.ExecutablePath)` you can try this

Comment: how can i run it with adminstraitor privilegs?

Comment: short and simple answer is open command prompt as an admin and run the script using command line.

Comment: Or you can https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771551(v=ws.11) try this

Comment: thank you very much, i will try it. but there is a way to permit doing this by psutil? can i overcome somehow about the access denied?

Comment: you're welcome. Unfortunately there is nothing much that we can do about it .
Please read more from here .https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/481

Comment: just open C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe as an admin, navagate to the folder where your script is located and run the script .for more how to run cmd and admin here .http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-command-prompt-as-an-administrator